# Minor error with extracting the fraction part of an IEEE 754 floating format number

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

So I have this function where I extracted my fraction part of the given int so that I can output it in hex form.

Here is my code where *result* is the fraction part which I then print in hex form.

```
// getting fraction part
    result = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int which_digit = 23; which_digit >0; which_digit--) {
        shifted_value = f >> (23 - count);
        int fractionn = (shifted_value & 1) * (1 << which_digit) ;
        result += fractionn;
        count++;
    }
```

If I'm given the number 8, my program correctly prints the hex form of the fraction part. However given another number like -0.749000013, my program prints 0x3fbe76 instead of 0x3fbe77.

Does anyone know where I went wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop end condition is `which_digit > 0`, so you skip over bit #0. It should be `which_digit >= 0`. You should also start with bit 22, not 23.

That said, your entire loop can be replaced by the simple `result = f & 0x7fffff;`. There's no need to go bit by bit.

Comment: why 0x7fffff? i know that 0xf would mean we mask 4 bits but please explain this

Comment: @shellysu Because 0x7fffff has the rightmost 23 bits set, and you need the rightmost 23 bits of the input.